# Excel Reconciliation

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a reconciliation that requires 3 columns to be equal so A=B,B=C instead of the forth column displaying True or False I would like to be able to show weather "None" match or display whichever column is not matching, either A, B or C?

Thank you guys

Comment: Mandatory: what have you tried so far?

Comment: =IF(AND(E2=F2,G2=F2),F1,"None")

I am going to assign columns, names in which to print to the fourth column to show the user is the wrong column. im thinking now do i require a number of IF statements to rule out whether one doesn't match or none match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IF(AND(A2=B2,A2=C2),"match",IF(A2=B2,"C",IF(A2=C2,"B",IF(B2=C2,"A","none"))))
```

Comment: Ok so moving on from that if I wanted column "e" to display the the difference between the cells that match and the cells that dont match as a number.